# SRVE0274W - JSF 2.2. on WAS Liberty 8.5.5.3

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, websphere-liberty

We are trying to improve development of JSF2 (jsf 2.2) applications on WAS 8.5.5.
Previously we have been running the apps on full installation of Web Sphere (8.5.5) connected with Eclipse Luna (and RAD) via plugin.

We have set up a couple of Liberty servers (8.5.5.3) on local machines and trying to run JSF application on them. However after setting up the [server.xml](http://pastebin.com/wnUdqDnd), we get this error (after all other problems were solved, we can't get past this anymore).

```
[WARNING ] SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for path-->/faces/*, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[Faces_Servlet:[*.xhtml, /faces/*]], application-->xxx-ear.
```

The same error comes from Eclipse and RAD, so it seems to be problem with Liberty configuration or Liberty it self?

By default the Liberty (8.5.5.3) does not support jsf 2.2, so it used external libraries to provide that.

Btw. If the jsf 2.0 feature is removed from the server.xml, it magically appears back when the server is told to republish it's content. It didn't seem to be connected with the facet value set in eclipse facets.

Any hints what to look for regarding to the error message. Could not find any information about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you upgrade to the most recent version of WAS Liberty it has a feature for jsf-2.2. If you continue to use 8.5.5.3, which is really old, then if you can get WDT to stop adding the feature by:

- Right click on the project
- Selecting properties
- Expand Liberty Server
- Select Required Features
- Find jsf-2.0
- In the Action column change the value and select Never

[image]

Comment: I tried downloading the 8.5.5.8 version, but that includes Java EE7 where we are suppose to use EE6. The last version with EE6 is 8.5.5.5, but I can not download it without a proper license. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24039425 <= I tried downloading the 'wlp-developers-ipla-runtime-8.5.5.5.jar'. Is it something else?

Comment: I can not find this WDT option you mentioned. There is some 'liberty' entry. 'project' > 'options' > find: 'server' | 'WebSphere Application Server Liberty Profile at localhost' is listed, but can't do anything about it. Did not find other options.

Comment: 8.5.5.8 supports both EE6 web profile and EE7 features, and doesn't need a license for development use. The simplest way to get all the EE6 features is probably to download the [kernel package](https://developer.ibm.com/assets/wasdev/#asset/runtimes-8.5.5-wlp-kernel) and then install the [EE6 webprofile feature](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/features-com.ibm.websphere.appserver.webProfile-6.0), that should give you everything you need.

Comment: @VilleMyrskyneva If you are required to use Java EE 6 then why are you trying to use Java EE 7 version of JSF?

Comment: @Alasdair I know this anomaly. I think it is because of the improvements in injection? (just a guess, there's a lot in this project that can not be explained with common sense. This is what was already selected as technology stack when I joined the project.). I did ask about the option to switch to Java EE 7 but this would require changing the production server WAS versions and due to licensing and burocracy it's not possible any time soon.

Comment: If you put jsf 2.2 in your app you won't get CDI injection. In any case if you have 8.5.5 and can go into production on Liberty there shouldn't be a license issue,  bureaucracy I can't help with. I hope the screenshot I added helped though.